# typo3 How to create a sub page with menu on the left column

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i am new with this, this is not my field.
however my boss wants me to"edit" the website's content, and this is more than editing the content.
Can someone help guide me. ps. the typo3 version is 8.7.8

So, this is now:
Now on the company website GLOBAL > go to dropdown menu of CONTINENT > go to dropdown menu of COUNTRY > go to dropdown menu of PROVINCE > go to dropdown menu of TEAM > then open page TEAM.

What I want:
In the COUNTRY already page content
with menu list of PROVINCE to click
When PROVINCE clicked > then open page PROVINCE
On page province again with the menu list of TEAM / etc

(See picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qAWo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in this way the problem description is too broad.

especially as in TYPO3 there are multiple ways to manage layouts we don't know how it was done in your installation.
So we can't say what to do.

---

In case your installation is done conform to best practise:
there is a site-extensions.
in the extension, the (BackEnd-)Layouts are defined. Either you find one Layout with two columns or you can add one.

If your problem is more an editor problem: there are different ways for creating pages.
Anyway you create a page and probably the content. Menus should be configured to be generated automatically.

anything else needs a lot of information (versions, configuration, templates, ...)

Comment: Im blind about this. in the another website (old different website), it is created by creating shortcut page, shortcut target "country name", and inside of the page is folder of the countries